# How much memory before it becomes rude?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory

I'm currently working on a web app, and have been inspired by a couple different apps out there (mainly Cloud9IDE) in how they hold a large majority of their interface in javascript objects.  This makes it incredibly easy to add features in the future, and also allows extensibility options in the future.

The question is, at what point does storing data in memory (via javascript) become rude.  I'm building a social network (think like Twitter), and essentially I would be storing an object for every "tweet", as well as some more broad objects for interface items.

Are there hard limits forced by browsers on how much memory I can use?  Will my website crash if I go over?  Or will the entire browser crash? Will it slow down the user?  If so, is there a general rule for how much memory will bother the average user?

Comment: This question seems too localized to me.  I can't think of any way to answer this without resorting to ballpark numbers that will be obsolete within a year or two.

Comment: The numbers won't be obsolete within a year or two.  If anything, more and more ARM devices with less memory (think tablets) are being sold, and I would expect that at best 2014's tablets have the memory capacities of today's desktops.

Comment: "tweets" are not exactly big memory hogs at 140 bytes + maybe some object overhead.  If you're writing a video editor in javascript, then you might need to worry about memory use.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Absolutely positively don't use anywhere close to 4 GB of memory.  Most people use 32-bit browsers, so the browser couldn't support 4 GB anyway :)

On a more practical note, remember that the more memory you take up, the slower your app will usually run.  Today's Intel/AMD (I don't know about ARM) processors access registers about 100 times faster than accessing memory that isn't in cache, so if you use a lot of memory you will cause [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29), which will slow down your application dramatically.

So, assuming that you want users for your social network, you should try to design your website to work well on as many machines as possible.  Millions and millions of people are still using Windows XP machines that are 5+ years old.  These machines might have as little as 512 MB of RAM, so if you are using a few hundred megabytes, you can thrash all of memory rather than just processor cache, as the kernel keeps swapping out pages that you want to use.  So as a rule of thumb I would recommend staying below 150-200 MB of memory.  GMail takes up ~100MB of memory on Chrome for Linux, so I think that keeping up with GMail is a reasonable goal.

Another benefit of keeping memory usage relatively low is that your users can more easily view your site on a smartphone.  An iPhone 3GS (there are still a lot of them in use) has only 256 MB of RAM, so staying below 200 MB in your website makes it easier for a smartphone user to load your site without having to kill processes indiscriminately.

Comment: I think your answer's use of "512 MB of RAM", "Windows XP", "256 MB of RAM" (for an iphone 3gs) rather proves my point about being too localized.

Comment: @KirkWoll When you start worrying about memory usage, you have left the ideal computer with infinite space and time, and you are worrying about real systems.  If you are designing for real computers, it's best to have some real computers in mind.

Comment: How exactly are you viewing how much memory a single web page is using?  I can't find anything in chrome dev tools, which would be my best guess.

Comment: @jwegner Tools->Task Manager under the wrench icon

Comment: I've never seen the exchange between cache and main memory called thrashing before. That linked article is pretty specific to the exchange between main memory and disk. If you're already wondering how much main memory is too much, you're waaaay past the threshold of being completely in cache.

Comment: @Charlie, from the first paragraph of the linked article, "The term is also used for various similar phenomena, particularly movement between other levels of the memory hierarchy, where a process progresses slowly because significant time is being spent acquiring resources." -- if your program can work entirely out of the available cache, you are gonna have one hell of a faster ride than if you have to pull stuff from main memory every now and then.  If you have enough going on that scrolling down requires a hit to main mem, it'll be visually noticeable

Comment: @mjohnsonengr Of course it would be faster from cache, but all the byte counts in this answer are an order or two of magnitude higher than any modern processor has cache for.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin What does scrolling have to do with javascript memory? Scrolling is a texture and JS objects have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Gmail now uses ~50% more. This is really crazy, never thought web-pages took all this memory.